# how to read and write data from json file

Tags: node.js, json

i want to write a json file with nodejs but i have no idea because i'm beginner

the problem is when i tried to add data to the json file, data does not increase but is overwritten, for the example, i have data "a" (total data = 1) then i trying to add new data "b" (total data = 1) because data "a" is overwritten by data "b" so my data is never increase just only have 1 total of data

this is my json structure in directory /user/userData.json

```
[
 {
  "username": "john",
  "password": "123qwejkl",
  "nama": "john somelastname",
  "no": "0128749726",
  "email": "john@gmail.com",
  "caption": "life is never flat"
 }
]
```

this is my nodejs code

```
 //const data = fs.readFileSync('./user/userData.json')
 //const jsonData = JSON.parse(data)

 app.post('/user', (req, res)=>{
   const username = req.body.username
   const password = req.body.password
   const name = req.body.nama
   const no = req.body.no
   const email = req.body.email
   const caption = req.body.caption


   const sendData = [{
    username:username,
    password:password,
    name:name,
    no:no,
    email:email,
    caption:caption
   }]


    const sendJSON = JSON.stringify(sendData, null,2)
    fs.writeFile('./user/userData.json', sendJSON)

    res.send(sendData)

 })
```

I know something is missing from my code, so please help me how to read data from json file then write new data to json file

Comment: Parse current data present in json file, then use push method to push new data and then save. currently, you are just overriding the file with the newest data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order not to overwrite already existing data, you have to read the file from file system, parse it as JSON, push new element (user) to an array and write the result to the file system:

```
//after you have created sendData object
fs.readFile('./user/userData.json', 'utf8', function (err, data) {
  if (err) throw err;
  output = JSON.parse(data);
  output.push(sendData[0]);
  const sendJSON = JSON.stringify(output, null, 2);
  fs.writeFile('./user/userData.json', sendJSON, function(err){
    if (err) throw err;
    res.send(sendJSON)
  });
});
```

I can see that you are creating some sort of user registration system. Please be aware of the fact that using files for storing data in a web application is not recommended. It may result in poor performance, low fault tolerance and possible concurrent data access issues (race condition).

In your case, imagine the following situation (in steps):

1. User 1 registers using your `/user` endpoint
2. Processing of User 1 request awaits I/O operation `readFile`
3. In the meantime, User 2 registers using same `/user` endpoint
4. Processing of User 2 request awaits I/O operation `readFile`
5. Processing of User 1 request continues execution (runs callback) and saves file using `writeFile` (initial + User 1 data)
6. Processing of User 2 request continues execution (runs callback) and overwrites file using `writeFile` (initial + User 2 data)

As a consequence, User 1 data will be lost (file including User 1 data will be overwritten).

Virtually all databases would prevent such situation from happening.

I would recommend you research the following topics: JS asynchronous code execution, JS callbacks, data concurrency, using a database in node.js (MongoDB is a good start).